# Maintaining single TLS handshake state across multiple subdomains on the same server

Tags: nginx, ssl, apache2

I currently have two different subdomains that I would like to host on a single server. The scenario that I wish to implement is when the first domain fails due to an `SSL handshake error`, the second domain should be able to redirect to a new third subdomain based on this failure information (for the same client). Therefore, while the first subdomain is unable to complete the TLS handshake and move on to the HTTP layer to do the redirect, the second domain is still alive and waiting to see whether the TLS handshake for the first domain got rejected or not.

From my current beginner knowledge of how servers are implemented, I believe that communicating this TLS state across two servers may not be possible. However, I am wondering whether this is something that is doable if I have a single server handling all the subdomains. Can I for example, maintain a single store of information about the TLS states connected with the two subdomains? Is this something that may be possible in either `NGINX` or `APACHE` server configurations? Or via some other route?

One of the possibilities I have explored is the [`map`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-nginx-s-map-module-on-ubuntu-16-04) command inside `nginx` where you can set up a variable, and then read it inside the server. Could something like this be also used? For example, I could set up the variable inside subdomain one if the handshake has failed, and then read the variable when I am about to redirect from the second subdomain to do a conditional redirect.

Alternatively, since my ultimate requirement is to be able to redirect from subdomain-one to subdomain-three if subdomain one fails, can I just redirect to a new subdomain using the error directive if I notice 492 error code (which specifies whether there is an error in the client verfication process) as mentioned over [here](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_trusted_certificate). I have tested this by adding an error page:

`error_page 492 /home/vagrant/flask_app/app_name/app/static/images/pixel_fail.png`

but it doesn't seem to be working.

Would very much appreciate help regarding this.

Comment: So, basically subdomain one and two are both loaded at the same time. Subdomain one fails on handshake, and subdomain two is holding off its response until it somehow knows that the first subdomain has failed. So, while I cannot redirect via subdomain one (which you rightly pointed out cannot redirect until the TLS handshake has been completed), I can still redirect using subdomain two. So, my question is whether a sharing of state (via some sort of variable or anything else) is possible between the two subdomains since they are both on the same server.

Comment: Rather than add comments please delete the comment and edit your post to make sure it contains all the information someone would need to help solve your problem. Make it easy for people to help you. Suggest you remove the "edit" section of your post and make it a single, consistent, easy to understand question.

Comment: @Tim This comment was a response to a question asked in the comments, which I believe they deleted later. But yes, I will make it more consistent.